# How to setup PhpStorm / WebStorm to work with Vite aliases?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, vite

Vite isn't supported by the PhpStorm / WebStorm yet, so given following Vite configuration:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
    },
  },
});
```

it doesn't recognize the following import correctly:

```js
import { getAllItems } from '@/api'
```

How can this be setup to work correctly?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Create a JavaScript file in a root of your project (name doesn't really matter, I'll go with `phpstorm.config.js`) and mirror your aliases configuration like shown below:

```js
System.config({
  "paths": {
    "@/*": "./src/*",
  }
});
```

Php/Webstorm will pick it up automagically. It's probably a good idea to add it to the `.gitignore`.

---

Another option is to create a `jsconfig.json` following the pattern below:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Read more on this solution in the docs of [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases)

Comment: another option is using `jsconfig.json` for specifying path aliases, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Comment: @lena yeah haha, I'd say using visual studio is another option indeed :P

Comment: I'm not suggesting using VSCode:) WebStorm/PHpStorm do support resolving aliases defined in `jsconfig.json`, so it's just another way to define your aliases. We can't afford supporting all possible ways to define path mappings coming from different bundlers, frameworks and plugins, so in the future we'd likely provide some unified way to deal with them in the IDE. And using `jsconfig.json` is one of the options we are evaluating now

Comment: Oh, sorry then :sweat-smile: I was a bit shocked that a jetBrains engineer advocates using VScode. I'm updating my answer right away!

Comment: Decent workaround. A bit of a pain to then need to define your aliases in 2 files, solely for the IDE however.

Comment: What about just giving us a way, in IDE settings to define custom aliases?

Comment: If I try System.config({
    "paths": {
        "/autocode-js/*": "./web/app/autocode/*"
    }
}); -- then import {...} from "/autocode-js/php-enums.mjs" is still not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnCarrell That would be nice, but versioning it as a config is a great way to share that little fix with a team.

Comment: You are amazing even phpstorm support couldn't solve this